# identify product after web crawling, price comparison

Tags: solr, machine-learning, web-crawler, classification, nutch

I am currently working on developing a price comparison site for which I crawl some e-commerce websites and extract some data from their HTML pages like price, title, metadata etc. I am at a point now that I need two identify if two products crawled from different websites are actually the same and assign a common label for both of them.
For example, lets say site 1 has as a title for a product the following string: 
"*Smartphone Samsung Galaxy S6 4G 32GB*" 
and site 2 has as a title for the same product this string: 
"*Samsung Galaxy S6 White*"

How can I identify if these two products are actually the same product, which I want to label in my site as "Samsung Galaxy S6"?
I have thought of using some machine learning techniques like classification or clustering. However, classification will probably require a big set of already well formatted products' labels (plus frequently updated) to act as the possible classes e.g. class "*Samsung Galaxy S6*", is there such a thing? Also with such a huge number of classes it may not be feasible.

I am using Apache **Nutch** for crawling and **Solr** for indexing and search. If there is any specific library or tool for those it will be very helpful, but my question is not specifically for those and I will be very happy to read any suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar for my project where we tag people names with their IDs, so basically the same person can have their name listed as the full name or initials, or only the first name etc. and we tag it to the same ID.

So for your case this will basically entail building an inverted index for your products and then scanning the title field for the product names and tagging them to a particular product ID. This way all Samsung Galaxy S6s get mapped to the same product.

This does not require any learning to be performed, you just need to have database to pick up all unique products from and keep updating your index as your product database changes.

All of this can be done at index time by writing an update processor for solr.

The implementation is a bit complex to put it all here so I've just outlined the basic idea that could help you out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sounds like a good, "cleaner" way. The problem with this approach is that it requires a database with all the products, which is not an easy thing to find and maintain (does such a DB even exist?). Maybe I can crawl one of the retailer sites that has most of the products and create the DB by my own. Btw I am curious, what will your suggestion be on determining if the indexed product and the product in DB should be connected? Some kind of string comparison on the title field to determine similarity and the use of a threshold?

Comment: Yes, a string comparison on the lines of what solr does. The other parameters like the threshold and how you want to analyse and match the strings will depend on your use case.